# Battleship project with python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python coding language, i got my first try of creating a battleship game, right now i am struggling of creating a loop for player and computer trying to kill each other. i tried to change the code into couple variant, but with no luck, is there another way i could have done it, or do i need to change my function, i tried to added new function such as gameover function where it will be check if all ships are sunken, but the result again the same, this is the original code that are currently function, any advice of how should i go from here ?

```
from random import randrange


ship_initial = ["B", "C", "F", "A", "S"]
ship_names = ["Battleship", "Cruiser", "Frigate", "Aircraft Carrier", "Sub"]


def get_username():
    """
    function getting username for welcome message
    """
    while True:
        user_name = input("Enter your name:")
        if user_name:
            print(f"Welcome to the battleship game {user_name}!")
            return user_name
        else:
            print("Please enter your name.")


map_size = 10


def create_battlefield(map_size):
    """
    function to create a map based on size
    """
    return [["_"] * map_size for _ in range(map_size)]


def display_battlefield(board):
    """
    function to display current state of the map.
    """
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))


def player_ship_coordinate(player_board, occupied):
    """
    function for player placement ship
    """
    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Battleship: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Battleship: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "B"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct value.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Cruiser: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Cruiser: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "C"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Frigate: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Frigate: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "F"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Aircraft Carrier: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Aircraft Carrier: "))

            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "A"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Submarine: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Submarine: "))

            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "S"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    return player_board, occupied


def comp_ship_coordinate(comp_board):
    """
    function for computer opponent.
    """
    for ship in ship_initial:
        while True:
            row = randrange(0, 10)
            col = randrange(0, 10)
            if comp_board[row][col] == "_":
                comp_board[row][col] = ship
                break

    return comp_board


def check_player_hit(comp_board, player_hit):
    """
    function for player hit or missed on enemy ship
    """
    row = int(input("Enter your row: "))
    col = int(input("Enter your col:"))

    if comp_board[row][col] == "B":
        player_hit[row][col] = "B"
        print("Computer: Battleship been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "C":
        player_hit[row][col] = "C"
        print("Computer: Cruiser been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "F":
        player_hit[row][col] = "F"
        print("Computer: Frigate been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "A":
        player_hit[row][col] = "A"
        print("Computer: Aircraft Carrier been hit")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "S":
        player_hit[row][col] = "S"
        print("Computer: Sub been hit")
    else:
        player_hit[row][col] = "M"
        print("Missed me!")

    return player_hit


def check_comp_hit(player_board, comp_hit):
    """
    function for comp hit or missed on the player ship
    """
    row = (int(input("Enter your coordinate: ")))
    col = (int(input("Enter your coordinate: ")))

    if player_board[row][col] == "B":
        comp_hit[row][col] = "B"
        print("Player: Battleship been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "C":
        comp_hit[row][col] = "C"
        print("Player: Cruiser been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "F":
        comp_hit[row][col] = "F"
        print("Player: Frigate been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "A":
        comp_hit[row][col] = "A"
        print("Player: Aircraft carrier been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "S":
        comp_hit[row][col] = "S"
        print("Player: Sub been hit!")
    else:
        comp_hit[row][col] = "M"
        print("Missed me!")

    return comp_hit


if __name__ == "__main__":

        get_username()

        player_board = create_battlefield(map_size)
        comp_board = create_battlefield(map_size)

        occupied = set()

        print("Player's turn:")
        player_ship_coordinate(player_board, occupied)
        display_battlefield(player_board)

        print("\nComputer opponent's turn:")
        comp_ship_coordinate(comp_board)
        display_battlefield(comp_board)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain clearly what it is you're trying to do.  It seems as if you're trying to do a lot of things.  Please be concise on your specific issue.

Comment: If this code isn't doing what you want, then please **explain** what it is doing, and **explain** what you wanted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment, but piggybacking off of NoDakker's suggestion and your follow-up question, you can try to create a 'Dummy Board' that displays a blank board & updates based on the player's guesses. The main function I edited was check_player_hit().

TL;DR changes:

- Added parameter dummy_board to check_player_hit()
- When comp_board is hit, it updates the dummy_board (signified by the letter 'X')
- if **name** == "**main**" creates a dummy battlefield and displays it; keeps displaying in the while loop

```
from random import randrange

ship_initial = ["B", "C", "F", "A", "S"]
ship_names = ["Battleship", "Cruiser", "Frigate", "Aircraft Carrier", "Sub"]
map_size = 10

def get_username():
    """
    function getting username for welcome message
    """
    while True:
        user_name = input("Enter your name: ")
        if user_name:
            print(f"Welcome to the battleship game {user_name}!")
            return user_name
        else:
            print("Please enter your name.")

def create_battlefield(map_size):
    """
    function to create a map based on size
    """
    return [["_"] * map_size for _ in range(map_size)]

def display_battlefield(board):
    """
    function to display current state of the map.
    """
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

def player_ship_coordinate(player_board, occupied):
    """
    function for player placement ship
    """
    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Battleship: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Battleship: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "B"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct value.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Cruiser: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Cruiser: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "C"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Frigate: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Frigate: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "F"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Aircraft Carrier: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Aircraft Carrier: "))

            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "A"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Submarine: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Submarine: "))

            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "S"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    return player_board, occupied

def comp_ship_coordinate(comp_board):
    """
    function for computer opponent.
    """
    for ship in ship_initial:
        while True:
            row = randrange(0, 10)
            col = randrange(0, 10)
            if comp_board[row][col] == "_":
                comp_board[row][col] = ship
                break

    return comp_board

def check_player_hit(comp_board, dummy_board, user):
    """
    Function for player hit or missed on enemy ship
    """
    print(user)
    row = int(input("Enter your row: "))
    col = int(input("Enter your col: "))
    hit = 1  # Assume there will be a hit

    if comp_board[row][col] == "B":
        comp_board[row][col] = "b"
        dummy_board[row][col] = "X" # 'X' will signify on the dummy board when a player hits a ship
        print("Computer: Battleship been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "C":
        comp_board[row][col] = "c"
        dummy_board[row][col] = "X"
        print("Computer: Cruiser been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "F":
        comp_board[row][col] = "f"
        dummy_board[row][col] = "X"
        print("Computer: Frigate been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "A":
        comp_board[row][col] = "a"
        dummy_board[row][col] = "X"
        print("Computer: Aircraft Carrier been hit")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "S":
        comp_board[row][col] = "s"
        dummy_board[row][col] = "X"
        print("Computer: Sub been hit")
    else:
        dummy_board[row][col] = "*"
        hit = 0  # Note that there was not a hit
        print("Missed me!")

    return hit


def check_comp_hit(player_board):                       # Refactored function to map hits and misses
    """
    function for comp hit or missed on the player ship
    """

    hit = 1                                             # Assunme there will be a hit

    while True:                                         # Randomly select a row and column that has not previously been fired upon
        row = randrange(0, 10)
        col = randrange(0, 10)
        if player_board[row][col] != "*" and player_board[row][col] != "a" and player_board[row][col] != "b" and comp_board[row][col] != "c" and comp_board[row][col] != "f" and comp_board[row][col] != "s":
            break

    print("Computer has selected coordinates", row, col)

    if player_board[row][col] == "B":                   # If the computer has hit a vessel, change the value to lowercase and return a hit value of "1"
        player_board[row][col] = "b"
        print("Player: Battleship been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "C":
        player_board[row][col] = "c"
        print("Player: Cruiser been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "F":
        player_board[row][col] = "f"
        print("Player: Frigate been hit!")
        hit = 1
    elif player_board[row][col] == "A":
        player_board[row][col] = "a"
        print("Player: Aircraft carrier been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "S":
        player_board[row][col] = "s"
        print("Player: Sub been hit!")
    else:
        hit = 0                                         # Note that there was not a hit
        print("Missed me!")
        player_board[row][col] = "*"

    return hit

if __name__ == "__main__":

        user = get_username()

        player_board = create_battlefield(map_size)
        comp_board   = create_battlefield(map_size)
        dummy_board = create_battlefield(map_size) # create a dummy board

        occupied = set()

        print("Player's turn:")
        player_ship_coordinate(player_board, occupied)
        display_battlefield(player_board)

        print("\nComputer opponent's turn:")
        comp_ship_coordinate(comp_board)
        # display_battlefield(comp_board) # for testing purposes
        display_battlefield(dummy_board)  # display the blank dummy board instead of computer board

        # Suggested while loop to alternate between the player and computer firing upon positions

        player_hits = 0 
        comp_hits   = 0

        while True:
            player_hits += check_player_hit(comp_board, dummy_board, user)   # If the player hit count reaches "5" all of the computer's vessels have been sunk
            if player_hits == 5:
                print("Player has won - game over")
                break

            comp_hits += check_comp_hit(player_board)           # If the computer hit count reaches "5" all of the player's vessels have been sunk
            if comp_hits == 5:
                print("Computer has won - game over")
                break


            print(f"Player {user} board")                       # Just included the redisplay of the boards for testing purposes
            display_battlefield(player_board)

            print(" ")

            print("Computer board")
            display_battlefield(dummy_board) # display dummy board instead of computer board
```

Following is a conclusion of a game where the player wins:

```
Player test board
B _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ C * _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ F * * _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ A * _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ S _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
* _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Computer board
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ * _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ X _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
X _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _
test
Enter your row: 9
Enter your col: 7
Computer: Battleship been hit!
Player has won - game over
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your original code and noted that it just displays the player and computer grids/boards and then exits, omitting any game loop.  There are probably a whole bunch of ways to compose a game loop to keep track of hits and misses, so using a lot of artistic license, following is a refactored version of your code.  It seemed simplest to list out the complete program code and note some key points to give you food for thought so my apologies for the length.

```
from random import randrange

ship_initial = ["B", "C", "F", "A", "S"]
ship_names = ["Battleship", "Cruiser", "Frigate", "Aircraft Carrier", "Sub"]
map_size = 10

def get_username():
    """
    function getting username for welcome message
    """
    while True:
        user_name = input("Enter your name: ")
        if user_name:
            print(f"Welcome to the battleship game {user_name}!")
            return user_name
        else:
            print("Please enter your name.")

def create_battlefield(map_size):
    """
    function to create a map based on size
    """
    return [["_"] * map_size for _ in range(map_size)]

def display_battlefield(board):
    """
    function to display current state of the map.
    """
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

def player_ship_coordinate(player_board, occupied):
    """
    function for player placement ship
    """
    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Battleship: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Battleship: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "B"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct value.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Cruiser: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Cruiser: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "C"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Frigate: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Frigate: "))
            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "F"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Aircraft Carrier: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Aircraft Carrier: "))

            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "A"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input("Enter the row for Submarine: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column for Submarine: "))

            if 0 <= row < 10 and 0 <= col < 10 and (row, col) not in occupied:
                player_board[row][col] = "S"
                occupied.add((row, col))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid coordinates. Please enter correct values")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    return player_board, occupied

def comp_ship_coordinate(comp_board):
    """
    function for computer opponent.
    """
    for ship in ship_initial:
        while True:
            row = randrange(0, 10)
            col = randrange(0, 10)
            if comp_board[row][col] == "_":
                comp_board[row][col] = ship
                break

    return comp_board

def check_player_hit(comp_board, user):                 # Refactored function to map hits and misses
    """
    function for player hit or missed on enemy ship
    """
    print(user)
    row = int(input("Enter your row: "))
    col = int(input("Enter your col: "))
    hit = 1                                             # Assunme there will be a hit

    if comp_board[row][col] == "B":                     # If the player has hit a vessel, change the value to lowercase and return a hit value of "1"
        comp_board[row][col] = "b"
        print("Computer: Battleship been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "C":
        comp_board[row][col] = "c"
        print("Computer: Cruiser been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "F":
        comp_board[row][col] = "f"
        print("Computer: Frigate been hit!")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "A":
        comp_board[row][col] = "a"
        print("Computer: Aircraft Carrier been hit")
    elif comp_board[row][col] == "S":
        comp_board[row][col] = "s"
        print("Computer: Sub been hit")
    else:
        comp_board[row][col] = "*"
        hit = 0                                         # Note that there was not a hit
        print("Missed me!")

    return hit

def check_comp_hit(player_board):                       # Refactored function to map hits and misses
    """
    function for comp hit or missed on the player ship
    """

    hit = 1                                             # Assunme there will be a hit

    while True:                                         # Randomly select a row and column that has not previously been fired upon
        row = randrange(0, 10)
        col = randrange(0, 10)
        if player_board[row][col] != "*" and player_board[row][col] != "a" and player_board[row][col] != "b" and comp_board[row][col] != "c" and comp_board[row][col] != "f" and comp_board[row][col] != "s":
            break

    print("Computer has selected coordinates", row, col)

    if player_board[row][col] == "B":                   # If the computer has hit a vessel, change the value to lowercase and return a hit value of "1"
        player_board[row][col] = "b"
        print("Player: Battleship been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "C":
        player_board[row][col] = "c"
        print("Player: Cruiser been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "F":
        player_board[row][col] = "f"
        print("Player: Frigate been hit!")
        hit = 1
    elif player_board[row][col] == "A":
        player_board[row][col] = "a"
        print("Player: Aircraft carrier been hit!")
    elif player_board[row][col] == "S":
        player_board[row][col] = "s"
        print("Player: Sub been hit!")
    else:
        hit = 0                                         # Note that there was not a hit
        print("Missed me!")
        player_board[row][col] = "*"

    return hit

if __name__ == "__main__":

        user = get_username()

        player_board = create_battlefield(map_size)
        comp_board   = create_battlefield(map_size)

        occupied = set()

        print("Player's turn:")
        player_ship_coordinate(player_board, occupied)
        display_battlefield(player_board)

        print("\nComputer opponent's turn:")
        comp_ship_coordinate(comp_board)
        display_battlefield(comp_board)

        # Suggested while loop to alternate between the player and computer firing upon positions

        player_hits = 0 
        comp_hits   = 0

        while True:
            player_hits += check_player_hit(comp_board, user)   # If the player hit count reaches "5" all of the computer's vessels have been sunk
            if player_hits == 5:
                print("Player has won - game over")
                break

            comp_hits += check_comp_hit(player_board)           # If the computer hit count reaches "5" all of the player's vessels have been sunk
            if comp_hits == 5:
                print("Computer has won - game over")
                break


            print(f"Player {user} board")                       # Just included the redisplay of the boards for testing purposes
            display_battlefield(player_board)

            print(" ")

            print("Computer board")
            display_battlefield(comp_board)
```

Following are the key points.

- The original prompting for name and board setup was left intact.
- The functions for recording player firing coordinates and computer firing coordinates were the major points of refactoring, returning a "hit" value if a vessel is hit.
- A player hit counter and computer hit counter is added to keep track of which opponent sinks the opponent's vessels and wins the game.
- A "while" loop is used for the game loop alternating between player and computer for firing coordinates.
- Once either the player or computer reaches the hit goal, the game is over and the winner is announced.

Following was the conclusion of a game test at the terminal with the player winning this battle.

```
Craig
Enter your row: 8
Enter your col: 8
Missed me!
Computer has selected coordinates 3 3
Player: Cruiser been hit!
Player Craig board
* _ * * * * * * * *
* * _ * * * * * * *
* * b * * * * * * *
* * * c * * * * * *
_ * * * F * * * * *
* * * * * a * * * _
* * * * * _ S * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* _ * * * _ * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
 
Computer board
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ * _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ * _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ * _ _ _ _ _ _
c _ _ _ b _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ * _ _
_ f _ _ _ _ _ _ * _
_ _ A _ _ _ _ _ _ _
Craig
Enter your row: 9
Enter your col: 2
Computer: Aircraft Carrier been hit
Player has won - game over
```

As noted, this is just one possible solution path, but it illustrates how one might use a "while" loop for game looping.  I included some comments to hopefully explain the purpose of the refactored code and game loop.  Along with these suggestions, it might be beneficial to consult further Python tutorial literature, especially as it pertains to loops.

Comment: My mistake on the last comment, there was a typo and i have deleted it. So, I have to ask any advice on how to just display the function for only displaying empty board instead of computer ship coordinate?